# How do I post a screenshot on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, images, screenshot

Please tell me, with all the freehand circles and illustrative figures you can muster, how one goes about posting a screenshot in a question on Stack Overflow?

Comment: The answers provided here are no longer relevant.  The preferred method is to directly upload to Stackoverflow and allow the image to be hosted on their pro imgur.com site.  See [New Image Upload Support](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/) for details.

Answer (score 28):

This way:

1. You go to the place you want to take the screenshot
2. You press <kbd>Prnt Scren</kbd> <sub>(Yey! [Our toy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/1974#1974) is [back again!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/23571#23571))</sub>
3. Create an answer/question
   [Any type of post will do http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/6651/pantallazo1p.png](http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/6651/pantallazo1p.png)
4. Click on the *Insert Image* button
5. Search an image provider (top google search will do)
    [I'll choose ImageShack as they are pretty reliable http://img134.imageshack.us/img134/3392/pantallazo2q.png](http://img134.imageshack.us/img134/3392/pantallazo2q.png)

   1. Click *Choose File* and select the screenshot file

      - *Optional*: Resize the image to an usable size
   2. Click Upload
   3. Copy the first provided link
6. Paste the provided link here
7. Click OK
8. Hurray!
   [Mission Accomplished! http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/6356/pantallazox.png](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/6356/pantallazox.png)

Comment: That's about an average of 500KB an image thar.

Comment: Was laughing my way through as I was browsing through this post, +1 for the entertainment :P

Comment: Gah, no wonder it's taking so long. Shoo!

Comment: @random: I love the smell of burning bandwidth in the morning.

Comment: The last image doesn't contain an image and it looks like you're stilling waiting for *sstatic.net...*

Comment: +1 That's the correct way for using circles! @o.k.w., you infidel, burn that into your eyeballs and never forget!

Comment: The only thing that would make this better is if the last screenshot was of this answer.

Comment: Why does your numbering reset after the first three? Other than that, *pure* **awesomeness**!

Comment: perbert, you **must** check [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org) (available in the official repos).

Comment: Nowadays, there is [the Stack Exchange Imgur pro account](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/), which is to be preferred, [to prevent image rot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75815/what-smart-ways-to-prevent-image-rot-can-we-come-up-with).

Comment: THIS IS HORRIBLY OUT OF DATE AND NEEDS TO BE UPDATED OMG THE HORRORS PLEASE SOMEONE THINK OF THE CHILDRENZ

Comment: It's true! This is terribly outdated! I use KDE now!

Comment: And all the images on this answer are gone. How ironic.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a post on popular Image Hosts you can use:
[Image hosting for StackOverflow answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19406/image-hosting-for-stackoverflow-answers)

Upload the images on those hosts and link to the uploaded images via the UI like what the other guys mentioned. That button is here:
[image: SO-Insert Image]

Comment: Shame on you for using soulless circles!

Comment: @John: It's an oval :P

Comment: There's nothing hand drawn about that circle!

Comment: That "oval" is an affront to all that is good and decent with the world. It is an abomination and flies in the face of huge manatees.

Comment: YOUR PROFESSIONALISM WILL NOT BE TOLERATED HERE!!!

Comment: OMG, I didn't know a non-hand-drawn shape is such a bad thing. I'm sincerely asking, why? Did I miss something? I can replace that with a hand-drawn one.

Comment: You prevented a full blown riot there o.k.w Good job on that circle!

Comment: Feel the enlightenment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775

Comment: Much much better! +1 for the indulgence of your sin.

Comment: @random: I felt enlightened... after reading the post, hahah.

Answer (score 5):

With the [new image upload support](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/):

1. Press `prnt scrn`.
2. Depending on your platform, you may need to paste it into an image editor and save it.
3. Click [image: the photo button].
4. Click `browse` and select the image.

Answer (score 4):

1. First you need to upload to a website somewhere. Free image hosting can work, as long as they allow hotlinks.
2. Link to it using either the normal HTML `<img>` tag, or use the markdown `![My Image](http://example.com/path/to/image.jpg)`.

Comment: Just linking is (no longer) the best way: uploading to the Stack Exchange Imgur pro account is to be preferred, [to prevent image rot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75815/what-smart-ways-to-prevent-image-rot-can-we-come-up-with).

Answer (score 2):

Hit the sixth button from the left in the 'post your answer' field. That allows you to build an image link.

Answer (score 0):

1. Upload it to some image hosting site.
2. Link to it.

Comment: -1 Technically correct but not exactly helpful.

Comment: Just linking is (no longer) the best way: uploading to the Stack Exchange Imgur pro account is to be preferred, [to prevent image rot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75815/what-smart-ways-to-prevent-image-rot-can-we-come-up-with).

Answer (score 0):

You *can* just go to uploadscreenshot.com and paste the image directly into an image upload site if that's easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Mac or Hackintosh, just reduce your pain and use [Skitch](http://skitch.com) (ignore it's prettiness - it is very functional).

Answer (score 0):

Use Jing - it is a simple free screen/region image/video capture utility for Windows, with a one click upload + place the link in the clipboard