# How do I post a screenshot to better illustrate my question?

Tags: support, images, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How do I post a screenshot on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28525/how-do-i-post-a-screenshot-on-stack-overflow)

I would like to add a screenshot. It would help explain the question. How do I include one?

Comment: Don't forget to add freehand circles if you are posting it in meta.

Answer (score 4):

Images are exactly like links, but they have an exclamation point in front of them:

```
![Valid XHTML](https://w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10).
```

which renders as

[image: Valid XHTML].

You can also use the image button, on the toolbar above the editor.

Answer (score 1):

You could post it on one of the [many free image servers](http://imageshack.us/) and then post the URL in your question.

Comment: imgur is better.

Answer (score 0):

As Robert explained, the syntax is:

```
[Sktich](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPaxr.gif)
```

You can also hyperlink an screenshot / any image like this:

```
[![Skitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPaxr.gif)](http://skitch.com)
```

If your system of choice is Mac OS X, [Skitch](http://skitch.com) is a nice option:

[image: Skitch]

It's free, does screen selection capture, has simple but usually sufficient annotation features and you can one-click send to your skitch account for (also free) online hosting.

---

On the Windows platform, the closest thing to it (though in my opinion, a distant second) is [Jing](http://www.jingproject.com/)

[image: Jing]

---

On Linux there's [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/)

[image: Shutter]