# How do I get a picture inside my post?

Tags: support, posting, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I post a screenshot on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28525/how-do-i-post-a-screenshot-on-stack-overflow)

I would like to to post a picture in a Stack Overflow question but it's not clear to me how to do so.

Do I need to host it myself and use HTML to refer to my hosting site, or can Stack Overflow host the picture? How do I upload it?

Comment: You accepted an answer so quickly I barely had time to post mine!

Comment: I switched accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When typing your response, click on the "image" icon (the fourth icon in the second group, next to the "format as code" button) and fill in the URL of the image. The markup will look like:

```
 ![alt text][1]

 [1]: http://your.url/blah.jpg
```