# How to upload images on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, markdown, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I post a screenshot on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28525/how-do-i-post-a-screenshot-on-stack-overflow)

How can I upload images on the Stack Overflow family of web sites?

Comment: no  did  you like this answer?

Comment: @Neil, You think you're the hallway monitor, don't you?

Comment: @Heath: He *is* the hallway monitor. He has a sash and everything.

Comment: @Heath Me and at least six others, apparently.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/

Answer (score 5):

Use http://tinypic.com/ site (for example) to upload image, then copy image's URL and paste it to text editor

Comment: Notice, [Tinypic is being discontinued as of September 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332659/383809)