# Bitbucket will shut down hg repos in 2020, what to do with existing links?

Tags: support, link-rot

As described in https://bitbucket.org/blog/sunsetting-mercurial-support-in-bitbucket bitbucket will delete hg repositories in less than one year from now.

For an example, I linked to the thg repo and one of my own in [How to set up Diffuse as Mercurial's 3-way merge tool and save from the middle pane into target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57119428/how-to-set-up-diffuse-as-mercurials-3-way-merge-tool-and-save-from-the-middle-p)

Given the timeframe, I can probably manually add comments or edit answers and questions I did, which are not that many. However, what should be done more generally? (Also, realistically my replacement links to my partner's server are not ready for long-term use either.)

If the original owner of a repo is still around then, I believe, they can re-register their to be deleted hg repos as git repos with bitbucket. (I will probably do that too.) However, at least the links with commit IDs in them will break then, unless bitbucket provides more extensive switchover support (none of which seems to emerge).

Comment: [145 posts](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Abitbucket.org%2Ftortoisehg) (there may be other URL schemes in use of which I'm not aware). At least not as widespread as [TinyPic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332659/295232) ...

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Abitbucket.org%2F 16k posts. thg is not the only project/user that will suffer this linkrot.

Comment: That search includes Git repos, I assume? And those are not affected.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right of course. Sorry. However, bitbucket was traditionally a hg host, so a sizeable portion of these *may* point to hg repos.

Comment: Of the first 15 on that page, 2 are actually hg repos. So it may be not thousands actually.

Comment: Hmm...seems like they cite the Stack Overflow Developer Survey as one of the reasons to discontinue Mercurial support.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog that is awesome, we created our own problem ... :(