# Suggested edit rejected by moderator but still pending review

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, moderators

As part of the 'project' to rescue TinyPic images ([the site is shutting down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332659/295232)), I've submitted a couple of suggested edits, including [this one](https://law.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/28282) which was rejected by a ♦ moderator. Note: I don't want to discuss the reason *why* it was rejected, merely the strange fact that it still seems to be pending review:

[image: Edit pending review]

It also shows as 'pending' on my profile page:

[image: Profile page pending edit status]

What's going on here? I thought moderator reviews were binding?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I was almost finished writing the question, the solution hit me: Law Stack Exchange just had an [election](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/878/378), and the review was made when the ♦ moderator was still a regular user without binding review powers. It's similar to a more frequently occurring situation where a ♦ is shown in the 'middle' of a close banner:

[image]