# How to get data on who viewed questions and profiles?

Tags: support, data-dump, api, views, community-data

I am working with the [Stack Overflow datadump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) and have a general question. I would like to obtain more detailed data on the "views" attribute, pertaining both to question views and profile views. That is, in the datadump we can see the total number of views, but not who viewed.

Is there an alternative source for obtaining such detailed information? As I understand, this is not available in the Stack Exchange API either.

Comment: This seems like a massive breech of privacy. I'm guessing this is not public information.

Comment: Thanks @Catija, but my intention is obtaining the SE userId, which is public information, and not any personal information. Moreover, it is given in each user's profile page. Therefore, I don't think there's a privacy issue there.

Comment: The SE user id is public information. Which user visited which question or profile is not.

Comment: Related: *[Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not available because

#### 1. Question views

1. There are questions having millions of views. Construct and maintain a database for storing each viewer details is heavy heavy costly.
2. You can easily differentiate who voted on the post. That is who downvoted you and you can take revenge action against them.

#### 2. Profile views

1. Some people may disturbed with some of your actions and hence downvoted your posts from your profile. So if you're able to find them, it is easy for a vote-war.
2. Those people may want to check your things but don't want to let you know.

So who viewed is a potential privacy issue as pointed out by Catija and also many services like Facebook/Twitter/etc. won't allow you to see who viewed your profile.

Answer (score 7):

The information does not exist in the database, so there is no way for you to get it.

Well, it does exist, but only for around 15 minutes. See [How are the number of views in a question calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-are-the-number-of-views-in-a-question-calculated) for more detailed information about how views are recorded, cached, and deleted. Basically, the number of views really is the only information kept.

Comment: yes. It is really hard & costly to keep and maintain such a huge data.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get more statistics on your total number of view for your **own** questions or answer, it exist an indirect tip to calculate thoses;

First, the question/answer must have an image.

If it does, then you insert the image tag to link the image to a location you have access to the log, not on imgur. After you can run like a [awstats](https://awstats.sourceforge.io/) on those log.

See there for the img usage;  [How does StackOverflow handle images from external URLs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115178/how-does-stackoverflow-handle-images-from-external-urls) or there [How to reduce image size on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253403/how-to-reduce-image-size-on-stack-overflow/253406#253406)

nb, If you can embed an image in your profile view, technicaly that tip will work too for profile view