# Avoid possible CSRF attacks by saving sort selection only when actually clicking

Tags: feature-request, bug, sorting, ajax, csrf

**TL;DR**: by storing the sort selection (active, newest, votes) in the page itself when getting a querystring parameter, SE is exposing its users to a possible CSRF attack which can change that sort without the users ever asking for this. I would like a change that will prevent such an option. What comes to mind is storing the selection in a separate AJAX call, after actually clicking the sort option we want to have. (Naturally a POST request,  like all other actions.)

---

Taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery):

> Cross-site request forgery, also known as one-click attack or session riding and abbreviated as CSRF (sometimes pronounced sea-surf[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voU2P.png)) or XSRF, is a type of malicious exploit of a website where **unauthorized commands** are transmitted from a user that the website trusts.

The default sort for answers, is by votes: (<sub>[sample question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456707/single-value-mysqli?answertab=votes#tab-top)</sub>)

> [image]

The action of clicking a different tab, e.g. "active" is actually a command: "Change the answers sort order, and keep that selection". Users might not know the selection is stored and applied to all other questions they will visit, but that's a different story - they still actively asked for it. Hence the command has permanent effect.

Now, suppose someone sends me [such a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456707/single-value-mysqli?answertab=active). It looks innocent enough, link to a question on Stack Overflow. I click it, take a look, close the tab and forgets about it. However, when viewing other questions, with more than one answer, I suddenly realize something is really strange. The answers are all messed up, in the wrong order, as I never asked to change the order. It takes a really good set of eyes to  notice this change:

> [image]

This is exactly an "unauthorized command" as the above quote mentions.

Can this please be nullified, by changing the way how sort selection is stored? What I have in mind is moving the part responsible for storing the sort option to trigger only in response to a POST request, and invoking such  a request in the click event of the tabs, before the page actually redirects. For GET requests, the sort selection should only be used on that specific page load and *not* saved on the server, to allow for [linking to specific sort selections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370869/allow-linking-to-a-specific-answer-sort-order-on-a-question-without-also-changin).

Worth to mention, this also applies to tag pages, e.g. after [clicking such a link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion?sort=votes), you will always be in the "votes" tab, in all tags you visit on that site.

Comment: My favourite trick along these lines is `![](http://stackoverflow.com/?pagesize=1)`

Comment: Yes, this is annoying, but it's hardly a *security* risk, so this might end up taking a back seat.

Comment: @ArtOfCode of course, not expecting anything, just thought that showing it as CSRF (which it really is, though indeed not really a "risk") might invoke a faster response.

Comment: @JeremyBanks LOL it really "works"!!

Comment: This seems like a bug in the UI implementation. It's almost certainly not an intended side effect of the implementation, that a user's persistent sort choice can be hijacked and changed subtly, without their knowledge. Can this be tagged [bug]? Maybe it might get more attention than it has in the last 5 years...

Comment: @scottbb thanks, don't think it will make a difference but I've added the tag.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/allowing-images-from-external-sources-opens-doors-to-serious-security-exploits) (a different and much worse security exploit that can be used alongside this one to mess with people)

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms yes, but..... images are a whole can of worms. Pandora box. This here is something really minor, compared, and so much easier to fix/change. :/