# Allow linking to a specific answer sort order on a question without also changing how subsequently-viewed questions are sorted

Tags: feature-request, sorting, csrf

On the Photo of the Week competition posts on Photography, in order to reduce the benefit of votes on earlier competition submissions posted as answers, links to the competition have the sort-by-active query string `?answertab=active#tab-top` appended, so that when users click them, the submissions will be sorted in descending order when they were added.

However, clicking on such a link causes subsequent links to that site to be sorted by Active, rather than retaining the previously-set sort order. This is a subtle "bug" that users don't understand how the setting might have changed, if they prefer to generally browse answers sorted by Votes or Oldest.

Feature request: allow linking to a specific answer sort order on a question, without affecting subsequent question views on the same site.

Comment: I retagged this as a functionality change, because this is how it's *supposed* to work currently. When you click on one of the sorting tabs at the top of the answer list, it appends that query string to the URL as its way of changing the sort order and telling the server to save it to the account when the page loads. Changing that behavior would essentially be a rewrite of the functionality for those tabs.

Comment: @animuson I appreciate that. But it sounds like a bit of a poor design that the "choice" can be made for a user outside of a deliberate UI action. Just a URL link changing a user's preference really takes the user's preference away from them. That is, why should a HTTP GET request change a user preference?

Comment: I agree with you, but that doesn't make it a bug.

Comment: Where do you get links with this particular query string *other* than by clicking on the sorting tab?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Users could easily get it from someone sharing the page URL after they clicked a sort which wasn't their default, which could be because they are intentionally providing a link with that sort specified for answers, or just because they don't think about it.

Comment: @Makyen I understand that this could happen in theory. But does such an unlikely coincidence actually happen, often enough to make it a real problem?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek That depends on each person's definition of what "often enough to be a real problem" is. I know I've seen this type of behavior on SE discussed previously (e.g. with changing the number of results displayed in search), so it's certainly not something that's only been noticed today.

Comment: Sorry for the late full-disclosure. It happens at Photo-SE's Photo of the Week competition posts. In order to reduce the early-contribution vote benefit, links to the competition have the sort-by-active query string appended. But after visiting that question, all subsequent questions continue to be sorted by active.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @animuson Breaking the user's expectation, due to an unintended consequence of a feature implementation, seems like a UX bug to me. If it's not a bug, is it "works as intended"? I doubt that is the _intention_ of the persistent sort choice to be hijacked by a URL query string.