# When JavaScript is disabled, sort orders other than "votes" are buggy

Tags: bug, answers, sorting, javascript

I normally browse Stack Exchange with JavaScript disabled, and reading, searching, etc. mostly work just fine in that context. However, sort orders other than "votes" are broken, for users with JavaScript disabled, in two different ways:

1. If a page has more than 30 answers, navigating to the next page resets the sort order to "votes" (e.g. if you're looking at the first page of answers when sorted by "oldest", and click the "2" button in the list of pages at the bottom, you will navigate to the second page of answers when sorted by "votes"). The cause appears to be that the URL accessed via the link ends with, e.g., `?page=2&tab=createdasc`, but the URL parameter is actually named `answertab`; `tab` on its own doesn't work correctly.
2. As of the [recent change to use a drop-down box for sort orders rather than clickable sort orders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376062), attempting to change the answer sort order without JavaScript enabled no longer works (the selection in the box changes but nothing else happens). This is probably unsurprising, given the nature of the change. This is a case that did previously work prior to the change, though, so is a regression for non-JavaScript users.

   The sort order can still be changed via manual URL editing, but this has become more difficult as a consequence of [the URLs changing and breaking bookmarks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377910) (and the new URLs are more difficult to memorise than the old ones were).

The second bug may be unfixable / not worth the effort, given that most users will have JavaScript enabled. The first bug, however, is long-standing and means that people who are linked to Stack Exchange from outside may end up missing some answers altogether, if the link embeds a sort order other than "votes", and therefore could probably do with a fix. (This is especially relevant because a question doesn't normally get more than 30 good, relevant answers unless there's something unusual or special about the question, meaning that this sort of outlier question is substantially more likely than the typical question to get linked to from outside Stack Exchange. Additionally, the voting mechanism doesn't work properly for questions this many answers – most upvotes will go to the first few answers even though the lower answers are usually better – meaning that the link is more likely than normal to use a non-default sort order.)

Comment: I do not think that JavaScript disabled is a supported site configuration, so this "bug" is unlikely to be fixed.

Comment: Just to support Cody's comment, as per [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/241919), "*JavaScript must be enabled*", thus bug/regression due to disabled JavaScript is unlikely to be considered unless the cause of the issue is actually tangential to it.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. The page you linked says that JavaScript is required for "the best possible experience", which implies that the site is meant to work without it to some extent (and indeed, in practice, almost all read access to the site does in fact work correctly, which is why a bug like this one is so noticeable). Bear in mind that Stack Exchange sites are often linked from search engine results, so Stack Exchange won't have much control over what browsers visitors are using – if someone has a non-JS browser and the site doesn't work, they'll just go elsewhere, not enable JS.

Comment: The JavaScript part is not either-or. For example, `googlesyndication.com` is ***not needed at all*** for full operation (and can be blocked without any problems). `cookielaw.com` is only needed for the cookie dialog (it fails without, but the resulting effective choice happens to be the least amount of cookies). Some other only affects the ability to vote (though possibly other things). `cloudflare.com` is only needed to render posts formatted with [MathJax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax) (only supported on some sites, like [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)).

Comment: "*Stack Exchange won't have much control over what browsers visitors are using – if someone has a non-JS browser and the site doesn't work, they'll just go elsewhere, not enable JS.*" to be fair, that also applies to supported browsers, which [SE officially only supports a few of them and only the last 2 versions](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/). Most pages may still work on older browsers, but if they don't work, I also doubt they will change/update the browser...