# Can we start indicating that there is an accepted answer at the start of the Answers section on a question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, accepted-answer, score

I was on Stack Overflow looking for an answer to a question. The default (I presume) sort didn't look hopeful, but I wanted to know if there was an accepted answer to look for or to just sort by score (accepted answers aren't always what you want, but I'd like to know one exists).

This is what I saw:

[image: The start of the answers section for a question sorted by 'active' showing 22 answers]

Rather than scrolling down all the way down, visually looking for the green tick, it'd be nice to a) know at least one answer has accepted (not always obvious if you find a question via Google) and b) jump to that answer maybe?

[image: Identical image as before, but with a link to the 1 'accepted' answer mocked up]

This is possibly more relevant now [we don't pin the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers).

Alternatively if we're concerned about influencing people to follow the accepted answer too much we can also link/highlight the Top Answer (wording from Google search results)

[image: Identical image as before but with a 'Top Answer' link mocked up]

Here is some pseudo-code to show it's possible (the `#anchor` link doesn't actually work, but you could easily figure it out, and just appending them is not as pretty as the mock-ups):

```js
javascript:(function addAnswerLinks(){
  const acceptedAnswerElement =  document.createElement('a');
  const acceptedAnswerId = $('div.accepted-answer')[0].id;
  acceptedAnswerElement.href = `#${acceptedAnswerId}`;
  acceptedAnswerElement.textContent = 'Accepted Answer';

  const highestScoredElement = document.createElement('a');
  const highestScoredId = $('div[data-highest-scored="1"]')[0].id;
  highestScoredId.href = `#${highestScoredId}`;
  highestScoredId.textContent = 'Accepted Answer';

  $('div.answers-subheader h2')[0].appendChild(acceptedAnswerElement);
  $('div.answers-subheader h2')[0].appendChild(highestScoredId);
})()
```

Is this something that's possible to add? Might be especially relevant now that we are  [Revisiting changes to answer sorting menu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376062/revisiting-changes-to-answer-sorting-menu-better-use-of-space-moving-menu-into).

Do we want this or a different design? Or if we don't want it, please answer with why.

Comment: Well,  this wouldn't be the case if you stuck to the original selected answer first sort

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I'm not following that. is that an existing sort button or a new option in the new drop down?

Comment: I mean the original design, where the accepted answer is on top wouldn't have this problem :D

Comment: Which wouldn't be a problem if we didn't have accepted answers as a relic of support forums in the first place :)

Comment: When would there be more than 1 'top answer'?

Comment: @OlegValter speak for yourself... On Sci-Fi & Fantasy SE we unpinned the accepted, but our questions can sometimes need the accept mark. Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800783/how-to-compare-a-local-git-branch-with-its-remote-branch) on SO, I want to look at both the highest voted and the accepted to see what the difference is.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I dunno, adding the number broke up the text. Maybe in ties?

Comment: I don't have anything against the proposal (in fact, an idea for a userscript has been on my backlog for some time). Just an observation that we wouldn't be in all that mess if accepted answers didn't exist in the first place (but since alas they do, here we are) + this is a joke response to JG's comment as a side purpose of the comment

Comment: [Yes, please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers/369577#comment1233308_369577).

Comment: @41686d6564 feel free to write that into an answer

Comment: Copying over [my comment from the announcement about accepted answers being unpinned on SO and potentially other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers#comment1233282_369568): "Speaking personally, not as a CM [...]: I like the idea of unpinning the accepted answer, but leaving some easy way to navigate from the question to the accepted answer (e.g. something like "This user has accepted an answer. `[Click here to jump to the accepted answer.](link)`.""

Comment: Personally, I think that sort of message would make sense as part of a banner (perhaps just above the answers) containing such a message, rather than next to the listed number of answers (as in your mockup).

Answer (score 6):

A suggestion from [V2Blast in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376598/can-we-start-indicating-that-there-is-an-accepted-answer-at-the-start-of-the-ans#comment1255442_376598) sugested:

> some easy way to navigate from the question to the accepted answer (e.g. something like "This user has accepted an answer. Click here to jump to the accepted answer..")

I've taken some liberties, but this is how I think that could look:

[image: indication of an accepted answer that resembles the post notices for bounties]

Personally, I don't think the notice should be as big, but I didn't spend much time on polishing this mock up. I hope it gives a good idea of what's possible.

Also it comes before the other answers, effectively pinning it there. That's not really what I think we're after?