# Answer sorting menu is cutting off the bottom part of letters

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, answers, sorting

When sorting things by the default sorting, the 'g' from the word 'Highest' is cut off.

[image: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376062/369802]

I'm using Chrome, at the most recent version (99.0.4844.82), and my zoom level is at 100%. If I zoom out to 90% there's no problem, but I assume it should show correctly at 100% as well.

Comment: I thought this was [fixed](//github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/issues/699).

Comment: @SebastianSimon You think my cute little screenshot is a liar? :P Perhaps it's just the same bug again then, things broke the same way again. If that's true, it's hopefully a quick fix :-)

Comment: I assumed that the fix hasn’t rolled out yet. ‍♂️

Comment: It's something with the font, if I remove the font family default rule it's fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNXxu.png.

Comment: Reproduced on FireFox on MAC, although less dramatic here, its just the bottom row of pixels of the g is clipped off. The best fix would be to resort back to the different buttons :)

Comment: For me reducing fontsize by 1 px (from 13 to 12) fixed this. Turning off `font-family: inherit` changed nothing.

Comment: FWIW, this, once again, seems to be specific to the Segoe font which has a lower base line. See also [Adjust Segoe UI’s baseline](//github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/863).

Comment: The issue occurs for >100% zoom, 80% and 75%, but not for 90%, 67% and 50% (possibly even lower, but I can't see).

Comment: The issue does *not* occur on any zoom level on the system I am currently using (Firefox 98.0.1 (is the latest—updated today) on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) with presumably 1360 x 768 pixels and presumably font "DejaVu Serif" 16 pt (claimed to be the default)). [Partial proof](https://pmortensen.eu/temp2/NoCutoff.png).

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Indeed, I also can’t reproduce any of these font baseline bugs on Firefox Nightly using Arch Linux. The font that is chosen by my system is always “Liberation Sans” where others have “Segoe UI”. This can be checked using the developer tools: the Inspector has a _Fonts_ pane.

Comment: Another minor bug: "Highest Score" is in title case, whereas the other two options are in sentence case.

Comment: Also occurs for users with <2k rep when editing a post: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEYSC.png)

Comment: @Justin: [The capitalization issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377333/335251) has been fixed.

Comment: @V2Blast: That's a different issue. For <2k rep users, when editing a post which has more than 1 revision, [this is what you'll see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypfOm.png). The 'y' and 'g' have been cut out at the bottom (in the Rev section).

Comment: @Justin: I meant to respond to your previous comment – I didn't notice that the comment just above mine was also by you. I've edited my previous comment to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has now been fixed for all zoom levels.

- 90%

  > [image: Image of fixed answer sorting menu at 90% zoom level]
- 100%

  > [image: Image of fixed answer sorting menu at 100% zoom level]

(Tested on Chrome, version 100.0.4896.127)

Comment: Might still be related to system fonts which can be different for each user, let's see what OP says.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar: I had the [same issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377327/answer-sorting-menu-is-cutting-off-the-bottom-part-of-letters/378205?noredirect=1#comment1259066_377327) on Chrome before, and now it's fixed. The font appears to be the same as OPs.

Comment: Looks fixed on my side too, yes :)