# Capitalization issue in the answer sorting menu

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, sorting, capitalization

In the answer sorting menu, "Highest Score" is in title case, whereas the other two options are in sentence case:

[image]

The screenshot provided in [Revisiting changes to answer sorting menu: better use of space, moving menu into a dropdown, ascending/descending sort options, clearer descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376062/revisiting-changes-to-answer-sorting-menu-better-use-of-space-moving-menu-into) has "Highest Score" in sentence case:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue. It is now fixed.