# Questions per page broken on mobile

Tags: bug, questions, mobile-web

Mobile is consistently only displaying one question per page (this is only happening for me on meta.SE):

[image]

Modifying the number in the link to 15 (`pagesize=15`)  just takes me to page 15 but still displays one per page.

I’m on the latest version of mobile safari.

Sorry if this has already been posted, I can only browse one question at a time at the moment (see above) so I may have missed it.

Comment: Can you try changing your results per page on the full site and then see if you see more than one on the mobile version?

Comment: Reported on Meta.SO: [Default page size when searching is 1 instead of 15/30/50](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376950/4642212).

Comment: @Catija that fixed it!

Comment: Cool.  I'm not sure why changing it on the mobile version doesn't reset it but I'm glad that was a solution.

Comment: @Catija is it worth closing as “can not reproduce?”

Comment: Eh... I'm pretty sure we could reproduce it since we know what probably caused it... it's probably the same thing that the bug report on MSO is. When you tried to change the number of results in the mobile view, did you try to switch away from 15 or did you just try to pick 15 again?

Comment: That's not a solution, it's a workaround. This is still a bug that better be fixed. @Catija maybe post the workaround as answer?

Comment: @Catija I never tried changing the number of results through the webpage--only through the link.

Comment: Oh, can you change it with the link now? Trying to determine where the bug is.

Comment: @Catija modifying the link is working as expected now.

Comment: Based on the above, it looks like this is a cross-site dupe of [the MSO post mentioned above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376950/default-page-size-when-searching-is-1-instead-of-15-30-50).  It doesn't sound like there's anything mobile specific here, so I'm just adding this to the existing bug in our tracker.

Comment: Related: [Allowing images from external sources opens doors to serious security exploits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279664/289905).