# Repost question due to lack of answers

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

I posted a feature request [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20726/drawing-sketching-tool-for-elaborating-questions) about integrating a Drawing tool into Stack Overflow.
But I posted it on the wrong day it was a holiday that day(Labour Day).
So contrary to Meta Stack Overflow I just received 3 answers to a feature request question and not much banter or criticism.

Now I would like to repost it so that I could get criticized a bit more.
What should I do?
What rules does Meta have on reposting questions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This information is just as valid on Meta as on SO:

[How to get attention for your old, unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions)

Answer (score 3):

That questions seems to have gotten some traction. But no, reposting the question isn't helpful because *somebody* will close it as a duplicate :)

Answer (score 1):

The same rules as all the other site.

- Edit the question to add more or less information
- Start a Bounty

Apart from the relaxed attitude on MSO the rules remain the same.

Comment: What does "Start a Bounty" mean?

Comment: You can give up some of your rep and give it to someone else for giving you an answer. Look at the bottom of the FAQ: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: If you go to your question there will be a "Start a Bounty" button just below the question.

Comment: Why don't you close this as dupe?