# Is it acceptable to cross-post questions to a mailing-list

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it wrong to ask the same question elsewhere?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22657/is-it-wrong-to-ask-the-same-question-elsewhere)

Is it considered rude to ask a question at the same time at SO and for example a Zend Framework mailinglist? Should I maybe post it first at one place and wait a few days for a good answer to come and then post it at the other place?

I will provide a link/summary to the good answer at the other location, wherever the best comes.

Comment: duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22657/is-it-wrong-to-ask-the-same-question-elsewhere ?

Comment: Incidentally, this is multi-posting, not cross-posting. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossposting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done so before now, when asking Code Contracts questions.

I would only do this if I had a reasonable expectation that it might take quite a while to get a response on either of them - so I wouldn't do it for "easy" questions.

In [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244290) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209166) I ended up accepting my own answer, having copied it from the MSDN forum. In the [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209185) I accepted someone else's answer but still added an answer posted in the MSDN forum.

I think it would cause problems if this were done a *lot*, but on occasion it makes sense.

Comment: yes, I would advise this for the "call in the specialists" type niche questions.

Comment: *on occasion it makes sense* -- agreed, but please only in combination with, when the problem is solved, copying results from one source to the other if applicable (like you did, kudos).

Answer (score 3):

Similar questions have been asked before (most similarly [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22657/is-it-wrong-to-ask-the-same-question-elsewhere)), and it's fine - as long as the answer(s) you get are cross-posted back to the other locale, so that folks can see you've found an answer.

Comment: "Similar questions have been asked before": I could not find them. Please, validate your statement with links to that questions.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23440/asking-a-question-multiple-times-on-different-sites & http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates & http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21011/repost-question-due-to-lack-of-answers-closed also

Comment: @Peter - see the four links I've provided