# How to Extend a Bounty?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, bounties

I have put up a bounty [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20726/drawing-sketching-tool-for-elaborating-questions) worth 100 reputation. Its going to expire in few hours from now.
However till date I have not received the relevant answers,
I would like to extend the bounty to another week and also increase the bounty reputation by a substantial value.
Is this possible? How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/

This is effectively completed, because

- bounty system is no longer tied to accepting an answer in any way
- you can issue multiple bounties on your question if necessary

Comment: Okay, but I don't get it. HOW do we actually go about doing this? I don't see an option to start a new bounty on the question I already have a bounty on. Is this possible only on "own" questions? (The question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137723/iphone-development-mpmovieplayer-crashing)

Comment: Sorry but having 100 rep wasted per week is not ideal. I would much rather have a way to extend a bounty for another week so those points can be awarded to someone who deserves it. Perhaps this works for someone who has 200k reputation, but not for someone who has less than a couple thousand.

Comment: I agree with Luke that some sort of permanent bounty would be fantastic. Especially for lesser viewed questions. But I could see that it could somewhat clutter the bounty section of some sites. I have had trouble getting anyone to even view [this](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/28972/convention-standard-methodology-for-calculating-real-prices) particular bounty on the Economics site, purely because the site is not as popular as SO and the bigger SE sites.

Answer (score 2):

There is no method of extending a bounty at this time. It is also not possible to place a new bounty on a question that has already had a bounty placed on it, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: AeonFlux should start a bounty and award this as the answer.

Comment: And then try and extend it

Comment: A Feature Request needs to be posted prior to that?

Comment: This used to be correct, but not anymore; see Jeff's answer.