# Add a diagrammer, please

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drawing/Sketching Tool for elaborating questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20726/drawing-sketching-tool-for-elaborating-questions)

SO (and perhaps Programmers and Code Review) could all benefit from the addition of a diagram creator/editor so that we can easily show database and code diagrams in our questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think there would be some easy way of creating a markdown-driven diagrammer, or maybe one already exists.  Then they could just throw an interface on it to allow simple constructs, and at the end of the creation process translate it all to that variant of markdown.