# Bug: Questions with embedded elements display as HTML tags in search results

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, images, search

As the title states. Unfortunately, [I can't post an image right now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4376/please-allow-image-uploads-directly-onto-the-site) to show what I mean.

Specifically, hyperlinks and images show as their HTML tags in the search results. Search "blue score" (no quotes) on Meta for an example of a question with an image.

I'm not sure what to do with hyperlinks, but images should probably be stripped down to a searchable marker that contains the image alt-text. Something like "[Image: image alt-text]".

Comment: Probably [status-bydesign]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this is by design -- searching is done on the cooked HTML. Getting to the raw markdown would require an expensive join to the history table.

Comment: The big issue is that whenever a question begins with an image or a hyperlink, the actual question text snippet is no longer visible in the search results listing because it's so long. Could we show more characters of the question preview?