# Uploading images via web

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, imgur, bandwidth

I uploaded an image from the web today, from http://imgur.com/.

However SO takes the image and reuploads it to http://imgur.com/, if the image from web is from http://imgur.com/ then it doesn't need to bother wasting space and bandwith hosting duplicates of the image.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64005/imgur-copyrighted-images-from-the-web-and-imgur-accounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is making sure that the image is *permanently* available, which when linking to an external image is not ensured. You can however manually do this via `![alt text](http://url.to.img)`. But please only do so when you're certain the image won't go away (I mean, even after years!)