# Upon edit, [img] is replaced with [image]

Tags: support, tags

I just edited the title of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149641/do-i-need-a-at-the-end-of-an-img-or-br-tag/), and noticed that the [img](/questions/tagged/img) tag had been changed to [image](/questions/tagged/image).

When I go to edit the question, remove [image](/questions/tagged/image), and add [img](/questions/tagged/img), it makes no difference.

**Here's [a short [unlisted] YouTube video](http://youtu.be/aAOjoqtS64o?t=5s), demonstrating the problem.**

What's going on? I'm using Google Chrome v26 on Windows 7.

---

[image]

Comment: Well, it appears to be a synonym tag, as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/image/synonyms).

Comment: @Daedalus Strange, since the tag preview shows them to be distinct! http://i.imgur.com/Y95Va25.png

Comment: @J.Steen See above.

Comment: Could you perchance add that image to your question, for ease of viewing?

Comment: @DannyBeckett Did you purposefully remove the "also: img" beneath the image-tag preview? ;) The visual clues are there. For the img-tag, the entire word is highlighted. For the image-tag, it isn't. Instead, at the bottom, it says "also: img", and the img in *that* label is highlighted. Yes, they're stupidly subtle visual cues, and they should be improved, but still. =)

Comment: @J.Steen Not purposefully :p I use Greenshot, which gives me a crop tool automatically when I press Print Screen. I just cropped to the descriptions. The entire `img` word is highlighted, because I typed `img` in the tags box.

Comment: @DannyBeckett Yes, but *nothing* in the image-tag-name is highlighted except the "also: **img**" at the bottom. It's subtle. But it's there. =)

Comment: Basically, the tag preview will show you target-synonyms of a synonym'd tag that you've typed in to help you pick better tags.

Comment: @J.Steen But why does `img` show at all, if it's a synonym? And with a different description? If I typed `cpp`, then both `c++` and `cpp` wouldn't show. Only `c++` would.

Comment: @DannyBeckett Oh, well. *That* I can't even speculate at. Sorry for the mixup. =)

Comment: @DannyBeckett Funny. On the synonym page, if you hover over the [tag:img] tag, it shows the correct description (the one for [tag:image]). Maybe it was a resent synonymisation and the preview data is still cached?

Comment: (As an aside, to prevent image rot, please use the Stack Exchange image upload, not the public Imgur service.)

Comment: @Arjan When commenting, there is no way to upload to SE's Imgur. It is also not possible to upload by browsing to http://stack.imgur.com - Futhermore, when I added the image into the question itself, it is automatically uploaded to SE's Imgur anyway. So I don't really know what you're getting at?

Comment: The image in your question [was NOT at the Stack Exchange Imgur account](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/145ca463-8c96-4de8-9e40-bfc22a32e3e6/view-source). (For commenting, I always upload the image using the "Your Answer" box, and then copy the URL.)

Comment: @Arjan Looks like typing the image URL in manually with `![](http://url)` bypasses the reupload function: [Uploading images via web](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65516). Good tip with uploading the image to an answer first!

Comment: Doesn't look like a cache issue; 3 hours later and http://stackoverflow.com/tags still shows the tag wiki for [tag:img] (which you can even get an edit link for), looks like a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a tag becomes a synonym of another tag, the questions under the tag do not get automatically retagged to the new master tag (in case the tags get *un*-synonimized, the damage isn't too great). So, there are still 1,300 questions which are still explicitly tagged with [img](/questions/tagged/img), which is why that tag still shows up (it's there, you just can't technically use it now).

Since it's now a synonym of[image](/questions/tagged/image), all new requests to use the tag will automatically be retagged to that master.

The only real problem here is that they don't provide us with any way to explicitly search for the synonymized tag to even be capable of manually retagging them to the master (or removing the tag if it's not a valid use), since it will automatically redirect the search to the master. So, if a moderator never ends up merging these tags, the [img](/questions/tagged/img) tag will always be displayed there (unless by chance users end up editing all 1,300 of those questions to have them retagged).