# Don't duplicate images on stack.imgur.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, images, imgur

User posted a link to https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3aUt.png in [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78875/how-add-new-tab-in-structure-when-manage-it). So I edited it to actually show the image. I didn't remember image syntax used here, so I used GUI button. that was much faster than reading syntax help and I expected it to gave me the same result as manual wrapping URL into image tags. I was surprised to see https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMZUc.png as created URL. I replaced new one with old URL and it worked good, too, so reupload wasn't really needed.

It seems each time someone will want to correct broken markup using GUI tools, new copy of image will be created. It's both a waste of time and HDD space. Could you add filter to GUI tools, so that if image is already on stack.imgur.com your tool would not try to upload it again, but would just use the copy available there?

Tested on [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com) and [here on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), in this very post.

Comment: Strange. In my experience what you describe as a feature always happened....

Comment: @Bart on http://drupal.stackexchange.com images are consistently duplicated when using gui to create "image from the web" with stack.imgur.com images. They are not for you? On what sites you tested it?

Comment: SO mostly...though I might have been imagining things

Comment: @Bart I just tested it, but only on the site that bothers me most. At least there it is a bit of a problem, maybe not big, but annoying ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Good point. We did upload to imgur regardless if imgur was the source.

But no longer, not from the next build - if the image comes from a `stack.imgur.com` domain, that's what will be used.

Comment: Nice, think it also answers [this other request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65515/152859).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Thanks. [meta-tag:status-completed] that one too.

Comment: So....I've been imagining things? That explains a lot....

Comment: @Bart - I believe the OP means they picked the image URL from the original post, clicked the button and used that URL. It would upload to imgur from that URL and return a new URL for the uploaded image...

Comment: @Oded that's exactly what happened. I don't remember image syntax used here, so I used GUI button. that was much faster than reading syntax help and I expected it to gave me the same result as manual wrapping URL into image tags.

Comment: @Oded Yes, that's what I understood. But I could have sworn doing that myself one day, thinking "hey, that's quite a nice feature"....If I come up with more features that work great for me, but don't actually exists, I'll let you know. ;)

Comment: @Bart - sure, just send them to my crystal ball

Comment: Oded, seems like implementation [has a little bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188333/not-able-to-add-image-from-the-web-stack-imgur-com/188343) now :(

Comment: @Mołot - yep. Saw that. Will get to it a bit later in the day.

Comment: Thank you. Hopefully people will see link above before posting next bug reports.