# Not able to add image from the web (stack.imgur.com)

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, imgur, uploader

I was trying to add an image in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188332/why-some-profile-pictures-is-not-viewable-to-me) as the OP requested. OP gave the image url which was from `stack.imgur.com`. But when I tried to add the image from the URL it show the following error:

[image]

I think the issue occurred due to [this request.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188186/187824)

I tried thrice but failed to upload from the web.

**Edit:**

I tried again in this question, but failed.
To reproduce:
Edit this question -> Copy the image URL -> Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> -> Select *From the web* -> Paste URL -> Click <kbd>Add picture</kbd>.

Comment: Why are you re-uploading from stacks own imgur? Just use this markup: `![](image_url)`, and you'll be fine.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - Have a look at [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188186/187824) for the same. Where it will not re-upload the image.

Comment: What can I say? Sorry, in a way it's my fault.

Comment: @Mołot - May be [someone else's fault](http://jsfiddle.net/CQQ6X/show/). :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a check for uploading from imgur into the wrong place.

This is resolved in the next build, as well as ensuring that stack imgur images will not be re-uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

My [request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188186/dont-duplicate-images-on-stack-imgur-com) was not to make these uploads to fail, but to make script just format existing URL as image instead, without duplication. Looks like a bug in implementation, or simply quick way to prevent duplicates (they cost money), but without user's convenience. Oded's answer to my request suggest it's the first case.