# Explanation for uploading & linking images

Tags: feature-request, images, uploader

Following up to [this question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175100/linked-images-get-re-hosted-by-imgur-without-any-warnings), I would like to put in a formal feature request now to have at least a link on the upload/link window for images saying "What will happen to that image?" or similar that opens a FAQ entry or similar to explain what happens to uploaded & linked images, what the media rights are etc.

Ideally, the page should know if the user has never uploaded or linked a picture and show an explanation right away in that case.