# Responsibility of SE (imgur pictures)

Tags: discussion, legal, imgur, inappropriate-content

So I have a strange question. I saw that all uploaded picture on SE get uploaded to an imgur-account. So I'd like to use this possibility (imgur pro) for my website too. But now my question: But are you guys(administrators) responsible for the content of this account? I know that an owner of a website isn't responsible for third party content. But because the pics get uploaded to a "private" account I'd like to know what the law says.

Because if somebody uploads illegal content. What happens?

Comment: You may find what you're looking for in Imgur's [TOS](http://imgur.com/tos), if not this may still be a better question to ask Imgur rather than SE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But are you guys(administrators) responsible for the content of this account?

Yes, [Stack Exchange Inc. has stated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151461/2915):

> **Imgur's "normal" terms of service *do not* apply to pictures you upload through Stack Exchange.**

> As far as rights go, **your deal is with us**, and is subject to *our* [terms of service](https://stackexchange.com/legal), [privacy policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy), and [cc-wiki content license](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

> That means that the images you upload are covered under our "attribution required" license just like anything else you contribute.

> We have a contract with Imgur LLC that explicitly states:

> > Imgur will make no claim of copyright to any images stored by SE on the Image
> > Server (other than Imgur's own copyrighted images and other works, if any).