# Associate uploaded images with the uploading user account

Tags: feature-request, images, imgur

Currently, all the data posted by a certain user is clearly associated with his/her account - questions, answers, comments, edits and tag wikis. Reaching any of those directly, one can easily tell who posted it.

That's not the case with images. For example when one reach [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtT51.png) directly (`https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtT51.png`) there is no way to tell *who uploaded this image?*

As the images are already hosted under Stack Exchange premium account, adding another parameter seem possible and with some benefits. When a user is uploading image, use his/her **Stack Exchange unique ID** (not per site ID) in such  a way that the above image will get such URL: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/201110/DtT51.png` where in this case 201110 is [my Stack Exchange global profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/201110/) ID.

Benefits of this association:

1. As stated above - directly accessing existing image will tell who uploaded it.
2. Easier to find uploaded images by specific user. Although [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64966) was pretty much buried by the community, in case it will ever get implemented having the images associated to the account will make it much easier.
3. Better consistency with the rest of the data on Stack Exchange - everything is posted under a specific user.

Comment: I don't think its possible via the existing SE-imgur _single-account_ linkup.

Comment: How would this work in regards to user account deletion then - do network account never get deleted?

Comment: @Manishearth should be simple enough for imgur developer, if it's not supporting such thing already.

Comment: @tombull89 even now when posts get deleted, images they might have contained still exist forever on imgur, just orphan. We can leave it the same way. Afaik account deletion is made per site, even for spammers so I fear the network account will stay but it's not really relevant.

Comment: @Shadow hm, good point.