# Can moderators see unused profile pictures I uploaded?

Tags: support, profile-picture, moderator-abilities

I put the default identicon as my profile picture aka avatar. I have also uploaded my photo and it is part of the uploaded pictures.

Is a Moderator able to see my uploaded pictures?

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: I don't think so. As far as I know, moderators, like any other visitor, can see only the picture you selected and can use their power to reset your picture back to default. Maybe developers or community managers got special tools to see your uploaded picture even if you selected to use something else, but can't say for sure.

Comment: A dev would be able to see it, even if a mod couldn't.  Not that they'd bother to check without some compelling reason to.

Comment: [This is the only reason I could see that devs would want to look at your upload pictures](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199353/213671).

Comment: If you upload something on the internet, it is usually best to assume that it will not be private. *Especially* pictures. My guess is that since SE bought their own instance of imgur, if they were so inclined they would be able to historically see your uploaded pictures. I doubt a normal diamond moderator could though.

Comment: @gunr2171: `s/devs/the authorities/`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to assume that everything is logged *somewhere* - how long that's retained and who has access to it depends a lot on the specific data and scenario.

As a more practical rule, you should figure that moderators can see anything *you* can see when viewing your profile - the only exception I'm aware of there is your *votes* which are yours alone.

Comment: Yup. What Shog9 said. And we can see histories of some of the information, too, where it can be useful for moderation duties. (And I'm not entirely sure why I felt it necessary to leave a supporting comment on Shog9's answer, of all people!)

Comment: I was always curious to know, do you (team/CM/mods) have any way to see list of uploaded pictures per user account? If so, it will nullify [old feature request of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130080/152859).

Comment: No, @Sha - for the reasons stated *on* your feature request. Although see above for notes on logging - if it was *really* necessary to figure out who uploaded an image (say, for legal reasons...) it would probably be possible to determine this.