# What to do to make a question easier to find?

Tags: discussion, questions, search, google

If I want to improve a question by making it easier to find in either SE search or Google, how would I do that?

The motivation behind this is that there can be multiple very different sounding problems that all have the same solution, so people with one of those should be able to find the question asking for another one of them.

There are some possibilities that come to mind, but they all aren't really great:

1. Purposefully ask a new question asking for the other thing and flag it myself 
   as a duplicate of the original question.
   Disadvantage: Intentional duplicates are bad.
2. Edit the original question to include some tag words that will make people find it.
   Disadvantage: Random words in the question that have nothing to do with the main question.
3. Edit the original question to contain two questions in one.
   Disadvantage: Only one question per question allowed.
4. Make my own FAQ with the same answer.
   Disadvantage: Updates to the answer don't get transferred. Also I would "steal" reputation from the original asker and answerer if people find my question and upvote it or the answer.

So what should I do instead?

Comment: Btw, I don't have an example case currently. I thought I had one, but didn't really. But now I'm interested, so I asked. If I find a good example, I'll add it.

Comment: Part of this question was already asked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243899/323179).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among the 4 solutions you've proposed, I think the second one "Editing the existing post" is the proper way. Now, looking at the disadvantage you've mentioned:

> Disadvantage: Random words in the question that have nothing to do with the main question.

If there is a case where adding lines in the title or body of question may be irrelevant or redundant to the question, Then I think the following work-around would work:

**Edit the existing answer to address that this can also be useful for <your_related_question> type of problem.**

I mean add note something like:

> Note: This (solution) can also be useful for the following type of problem(s):
>
> <Wrtie your related question/problem you think significant and this answer can help visitors looking for similar problem(s)>

In this way one can be in position to find out the answer by typing the text (of the related question you mentioned as a note in the answer) in search bar.