# How can I download all images I have uploaded to Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-declined, images

How can I download all the images I have uploaded to Stack Exchange as part of questions or answers?

Comment: A script which visits each of your questions and answers and searches their markdown for something that looks like an imgur link, spits out the image URLs and question titles and then downloads each image? sounds like something I could hack out in Python, but I'd rather sleep instead. Maybe tomorrow, if i'm energetic.

Comment: @cat: Of course, you'd have to verify the the uploader as well, since an edit by someone else could have uploaded an image (on your behalf).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130080/associate-uploaded-images-with-the-uploading-user-account.

Comment: @Werner Um. That's bordering on the impractically complex; one would need to grep all of a post's revsions for imgur links and make sure you're the one who added it -- it would be nondeterministic at best.

Comment: Adding [tag:feature-request] because that's obviously something that isn't possible at the moment. Franck, feel free to suggest something, I can think about a way too if you want and add it into the post.

Comment: Not to mention stuff you just uploaded but never posted, so you could link to the images in a comment later. [Oh look: a cloud in the desert.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBh38.png)

Answer (score 5):

We don't store who uploaded an image anywhere (except maybe being able to look it up in the server logs) and we don't have any desire to ever do so. You could get a portion of these by looking through the Data Explorer for posts which have images and extract the URLs, but that:

1. wouldn't include now-deleted posts
2. wouldn't include images that never got used in a post
3. wouldn't include images you uploaded to other users' posts
4. would include images other users inserted into your posts

You could solve 4 with an extra query to the PostHistory table for the post, and could solve 3 with just another separate query.