# Spamming Upload To Stack Imgur

Tags: discussion, spam

I am wondering if a thing like this is allowed or not. What I know is that once we upload an image, it will stay in the Stack Imgur account (even when the link to the pic is removed from post), and I also know there is nothing unlimited in this world.

So let's get to the point, is it allowed for someone to spam upload images (or even upload them automatically)? They can also use an account with enough reputation to upload unlimited images to Imgur.

If it is allowed, will it fill up the current Stack Imgur storage on the server?

Comment: I think you're begging the question here.  Of course it's not allowed.  I'm too lazy to read through the terms of service at http://stackexchange.com/legal but it would be very weird if there wasn't a clause against DoSsing the service.

Comment: @tripleee ,then what kind of violations associated with it , and what is the link to page with that rule ( not allowing upload spam )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there is nothing stopping a user from uploading unlimited amount of images to i.stack.imgur.

There are no checks, and even no way to know [who uploaded what picture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130080/associate-uploaded-images-with-the-uploading-user-account).

**However**, keep in mind the following:

- imgur hosts *billions* of images. Even one user uploading 10000 images would be tiny drop in the ocean for them.
- Without Stack Exchange account, one can't upload images to the i.stack.imgur domain - SE are using API with their own private key as far as I know. So spammers are nuked, and can't use this route anymore.
- Anyone can do the same (upload spam) with the ordinary imgur.com website.

So bottom line: of course it's "not allowed", but there is also nothing to be done and it's much less of a problem than one might think.

Comment: yeah , 1 image max size is 2 mb , and you can upload 1 picture every 1 second with javascript ( or else ) , 1 minute have 60 second , 1 hour have  60 minutes , and 1 day have 24 hour , so then 86400 x 2 = 172800 mb / day , 172 giga byte per day

Comment: just to know , everyone that hate stack exchange can use that way to destroy partnership with imgur

Comment: altough noone will do it because everyone ❤StackExchange

Comment: @user6668201 There's a flaw in that logic. Why would that destroy the relationship between the companies? First off, SE *pays* imgur for this service. Second off, imgur are perfectly capable of understanding that it's a disgruntled user doing this, not SE themselves, and that one user can be blocked.

Comment: @user6668201  - They can detect that abuse.  Why are you even asking about this?