# Given an imgur image URL, can one see which user uploaded it, and if so, how?

Tags: support, privacy, uploader

Given an imgur image URL (e.g., https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZRVq.png, I uploaded it just for the example), can one see which user uploaded it, and if so, how?

Comment: [Related feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130080/associate-uploaded-images-with-the-uploading-user-account), maybe a dupe as implementing this would mean what you ask about will be possible.

Answer (score 11):

No. I'm not sure if that information is stored at all, but it's certainly not available to the public. The IDs (in your case `ZZRVq`) are generated randomly and provide no indication about the upload time either. EXIF data and the like are also stripped, according to a quick test.

You *could* search for the URL on stackexchange.com: [`url:"https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZRVq.png"`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FZZRVq.png%22) and figure out in which posts it's used, and check the revision history to see who added it. But that does not guarantee it wasn't used (and uploaded) earlier by another user. With SEDE you could go through the entire post history, detecting now-deleted usages, but for larger sites such a query is likely to time out. And it still wouldn't detect usages in now-deleted posts.

Comment: It also wouldn't detect images originally uploaded in chat.