# Is it possible to post an image?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

I am trying to get help with a UI question, and think it would really help everyone answering if I could load an image of what my UI currently looks like. Is that possible?

Comment: See [Please allow image uploads directly onto the site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4376)

Comment: And [How to upload an image to a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75491)

Comment: In what site do you need this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need 10 reputation to do this** (enough for the *remove new user restrictions permission), however you can then include images using:

- HTML `<img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">`
- Markdown `![sample image](http://example.com/img.jpg)`
- The editor toolbar button - which looks like [image: editor insert image button]

*Copied largely from the privileges FAQ*

Comment: True, it was missing from the linked faq I [added it now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post/75498#75498) :)